# Oracle 12c export stuck forever if any table has default sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Recently I came across an issue while exporting database dump from one of the Oracle 12c database schema. The export got stuck forever in a table which has a default sequence like below:

```
create sequence TEST_SEQ_1 start with 1;

create table TEST_TABLE_1(
    SEQ_NO NUMBER(10) DEFAULT TEST_SEQ_1.NEXTVAL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

I could only proceed with the export after dropping the table containing default sequence. Do I need to use any additional parameter in the export or it is an issue with the export utility? IMHO, if the table creation is allowed in the above fashion, export utility should also be able to export the table.

PS: Due to restrictions, I could not use expdp and I have not tried the behavior in expdp.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

**export command:**

```
exp abc/xyz@test file=testdmp.dmp log=testdmp_exp.log

Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Fri Aug 11 19:32:48 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Advanced Analytics and Real Applicat
Export done in AL32UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                   TEST_TABLE_1          0 rows exported
                                          ^^
                                          ||
                                          ||
                                      Stuck here
```

Comment: Can you provide Oracle version that you are having trouble with?

Comment: Could you add the command you are using to export the data/schema/sequence? Or explain how you are "exporting" the data/schema/sequence?

Comment: I am using Oracle 12c

Comment: It's working fine for me on 12.2.0.1 version. So let us see how you are exporting and which version you are currently using.

Comment: Updated the details. I am using oracle client version 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: Command executed for me with 12.1.0.1 but fails with ORA-1455. You should head to support,oracle.com and log a case. I suspect this is already a known issue with workaround of using expdp. Now it is interesting to me as to why expdp is restricted.

Comment: Can you see anything in the Oracle logs on the server that might indicate errors?

Comment: Oracle desupported exp as of version 11, so Oracle Support won't help you.  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-901CBBE0-65FB-439E-942D-F2038C18BCD2.htm#SUTIL3634

Comment: @Raj I understand expdp is a better alternative of exp. However, as the case is we just don't have necessary access for expdp.

Comment: @BongCon you should tell those who make/set policies that the utility they want you to use is not supported anymore. Perhaps they don't know. Either way, if exp is unsupported, support wont help you as CM_Dayton mentioned before (unless you are on some kind of exception list).